# Why HTML5 Video seek doesn't work if there is no direct file link?

Tags: html, video, model-view-controller, streaming

I use this (HTML file):

```
<video width="480" height="320" controls="controls" autoplay="autoplay">
    <source src="Video.mp4" type="video/mp4">    
</video>
```

Video file located in the same folder with HTML page and seeking bar work perfecly.

But,

I try to do that (HTML file):

```
<video width="480" height="320" controls="controls" autoplay="autoplay">
    <source src="http://localhost:32750/Resources/Video" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

And in the controller (MVC):

```
   public ActionResult Video() {           
      return File("Video.mp4", "video/mp4");
   }
```

Video plays correct, but seeking bar doesn't work! I very surprised. Think tnat "video" component "think" that this is video stream, and don't work.

Any ideas?

Comment: if your controller isn't able to support byterange requests (which your server probably does) then it tries to return the entire file rather than streaming it.

Answer (score 0):

In your second case the video is actually being streamed from the local server (assuming your localhost server supports streaming) - so it will behave in the same way as a regular video file being streamed.

There are ways to have a seek bar with thumbnails in a streamed video - you may need to have a separate thumbnail track to get the functionality you want, depending on your requirements.